# What DDR3L PC4 means ( stands for )?

Tags: memory, hardware

I read a bit and found that DDR3L is a low voltage ram (1.3 something ) and on the most of the boards i am usually seeing DDR3L *PC3*.
But i stumble upon DDR3L PC4.
What this PC4 stands for?

Comment: https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-memory/differences-in-memory-speed-and-data-rate

Comment: @AlexD Thank you. I found this too: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/quick-dirty-guide-ram-need-know/

But still it is strange how DDR3 ram can have PC4 - speeds

Answer (score 0):

I found that on the seller site there is a mistake and instead of PC3 they writed PC4 :D

So there is no such a thing like DDR3 PC4 ram :D
If your ram is DDR3 you will have also PC3 on the sticker
If your ram is DDR4 you will have PC4 on the sticker